# I Implements class and method but it still asks to implement

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, implementation

I am using symfony2 ,doctroin2 and calendR.

I am trying to integrate calendR with doctrine2.

I made service as discribed [here](http://yohan.giarel.li/CalendR/symfony2.html)

```
services:
  booking_repository:
    class:           Acme\UserBundle\Entity\EventRepository
    factory_service: doctrine.orm.default_entity_manager
    factory_method:  getRepository
    arguments:       ['UserBundle:MutorSche']
    tags:
        - { name: calendr.event_provider }
```

then I made EventRepository as discribed [here](http://yohan.giarel.li/CalendR/doctrine2.html)

```
    class EventRepository extends EntityRepository
    {
        public function getEventsQueryBuilder(\DateTime $begin, \DateTime $end, array $options = array())
        {
            $qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('e');

            return QueryHelper::addEventQuery($qb, 'e.begin', 'e.end', $begin, $end)
                ->getQuery()
                ->getResults()
            ;
        }
    }
```

then I made entity like this below

```
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * MutorSche
 *
 * @ORM\Table()
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\HasLifecycleCallbacks
 */

class MutorSche implements \CalendR\Event\Provider\ProviderInterface
{
/**
 * @var integer
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
 */
private $id;


function getEvents(\DateTime $begin, \DateTime $end, array $options = array()){

}
```

I think it implements \CalendR\Event\Provider\ProviderInterface class and function getEvents

but it still says,

```
ErrorException: Catchable Fatal Error: Argument 2 passed to     CalendR\Event\Manager::addProvider() must implement interface CalendR\Event\Provider\ProviderInterface, instance of Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository given, called in /Users/whitebear/httproot/muty/app/cache/dev/appDevDebugProjectContainer.php on line 1440 and defined in /Users/whitebear/httproot/muty/vendor/yohang/calendr/src/CalendR/Event/Manager.php line 101
```

my stacktrace is below.
Please give me some hint.

```
in /Users/whitebear/httproot/mutor/vendor/yohang/calendr/src/CalendR/Event/Manager.php line 101
    at ErrorHandler->handle('4096', 'Argument 2 passed to CalendR\Event\Manager::addProvider() must implement interface CalendR\Event\Provider\ProviderInterface, instance of Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository given, called in /Users/whitebear/httproot/mutor/app/cache/dev/appDevDebugProjectContainer.php on line 1440 and defined', '/Users/whitebear/httproot/mutor/vendor/yohang/calendr/src/CalendR/Event/Manager.php', '101', array('name' => 'booking_repository')) in /Users/whitebear/httproot/mutor/vendor/yohang/calendr/src/CalendR/Event/Manager.php line 101
    at Manager->addProvider('booking_repository', object(EntityRepository)) in /Users/whitebear/httproot/mutor/app/cache/dev/appDevDebugProjectContainer.php line 1440
    at appDevDebugProjectContainer->getFrequenceWebCalendr_Event_ManagerService() in /Users/whitebear/httproot/mutor/app/bootstrap.php.cache line 129
    at Container->get('frequence_web_calendr.event.manager') in /Users/whitebear/httproot/mutor/app/cache/dev/appDevDebugProjectContainer.php line 1457
    at appDevDebugProjectContainer->getFrequenceWebCalendr_FactoryService() in /Users/whitebear/httproot/mutor/app/bootstrap.php.cache line 129
    at Container->get('frequence_web_calendr.factory') in /Users/whitebear/httproot/mutor/app/cache/dev/appDevDebugProjectContainer.php line 1473
    at appDevDebugProjectContainer->getFrequenceWebCalendr_TwigExtensionService() in /Users/whitebear/httproot/mutor/app/bootstrap.php.cache line 129
    at Container->get('frequence_web_calendr.twig_extension') in /Users/whitebear/httproot/mutor/app/cache/dev/appDevDebugProjectContainer.php line 4607
    at appDevDebugProjectContainer->getTwigService() in /Users/whitebear/httproot/mutor/app/bootstrap.php.cache line 129
    at Container->get('twig') in /Users/whitebear/httproot/mutor/app/cache/dev/appDevDebugProjectContainer.php line 100
    at appDevDebugProjectContainer->getAssetic_AssetManagerService() in /Users/whitebear/httproot/mutor/app/bootstrap.php.cache line 129
    at Container->get('assetic.asset_manager') in /Users/whitebear/httproot/mutor/app/cache/dev/appDevDebugProjectContainer.php line 2032
    at appDevDebugProjectContainer->getRouting_LoaderService() in /Users/whitebear/httproot/mutor/app/bootstrap.php.cache line 129
    at Container->get('routing.loader') in /Users/whitebear/httproot/mutor/app/cache/dev/classes.php line 1426
    at Router->getRouteCollection() in /Users/whitebear/httproot/mutor/app/cache/dev/classes.php line 1218
    at Router->getMatcher() in /Users/whitebear/httproot/mutor/app/cache/dev/classes.php line 1205
    at Router->match('/') in /Users/whitebear/httproot/mutor/app/cache/dev/classes.php line 3611
    at RouterListener->onKernelRequest(object(GetResponseEvent))
    at call_user_func(array(object(RouterListener), 'onKernelRequest'), object(GetResponseEvent)) in /Users/whitebear/httproot/mutor/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/HttpKernel/Debug/TraceableEventDispatcher.php line 451
    at Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Debug\{closure}(object(GetResponseEvent))
    at call_user_func(object(Closure), object(GetResponseEvent)) in /Users/whitebear/httproot/mutor/app/cache/dev/classes.php line 3415
    at EventDispatcher->doDispatch(array(object(Closure), object(Closure), object(Closure), object(Closure), object(Closure), object(Closure), object(Closure), object(Closure), object(Closure)), 'kernel.request', object(GetResponseEvent)) in /Users/whitebear/httproot/mutor/app/cache/dev/classes.php line 3348
    at EventDispatcher->dispatch('kernel.request', object(GetResponseEvent)) in /Users/whitebear/httproot/mutor/app/cache/dev/classes.php line 3512
    at ContainerAwareEventDispatcher->dispatch('kernel.request', object(GetResponseEvent)) in /Users/whitebear/httproot/mutor/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/HttpKernel/Debug/TraceableEventDispatcher.php line 139
    at TraceableEventDispatcher->dispatch('kernel.request', object(GetResponseEvent)) in /Users/whitebear/httproot/mutor/app/bootstrap.php.cache line 992
    at HttpKernel->handleRaw(object(Request), '1') in /Users/whitebear/httproot/mutor/app/bootstrap.php.cache line 977
    at HttpKernel->handle(object(Request), '1', true) in /Users/whitebear/httproot/mutor/app/bootstrap.php.cache line 1103
    at ContainerAwareHttpKernel->handle(object(Request), '1', true) in /Users/whitebear/httproot/mutor/app/bootstrap.php.cache line 413
    at Kernel->handle(object(Request)) in /Users/whitebear/httproot/mutor/web/app_dev.php line 26
```

Comment: Did you add FrequenceWebCalendRBundle to composer as it said in the documentation for Symfony2 ?

Comment: YES,I have installed with omposer.json      "frequence-web/calendr-bundle": "dev-master" ,I confirm that 'frequence-web' dir exists under vendor directory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should implement the `ProviderInterface` in your `EventRepository`.

Have a look at the [EventRepositoryTrait](https://github.com/yohang/CalendR/blob/master/src/CalendR/Extension/Doctrine2/EventRepository.php) for an example. (Be aware that this is a trait, so you'll have to add the `implements ProviderInterface` to your repository class)

Comment: mmmm,I might not understand though,,, i changed EventRepository classes  class EventRepository extends EntityRepository implements \CalendR\Event\Provider\ProviderInterface,but in vain.Also my EventRepository class is just copy and paste from that web site.I am not sure what to do....